# All of my effects are disabled in Photoshop!

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I don't know how to change them back:

[image: disabled effects]

Comment: can you show more of that layer? also what type of object is it in the layer?

Comment: I copied the layers into a new image and it is working again

Comment: was that layer in a hidden folder? that's the only way I can reproduce it and not locked, just dimmed.

Answer (score 2):

hey try this 
go to Layer > Layer Style > Show All Effects (Second from the bottom)however clicking that and disabling all effects would cause something similar to you're Problem